# Surjectivity of operator $(Vf)(t)= \begin{cases} f(t-1) & \text{if $x\geq1 $ } \\ 0 & \text{if $x<1 $} \end{cases}$in $L_2(0, \infty)$

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $V:L_2(0, \infty)\to L_2(0, \infty)$ defined by

> $(Vf)(t)=
> \begin{cases}
>  f(t-1) & \text{if $x\geq1 $ } \\
> 0 & \text{if $x<1 $}
> \end{cases}$

I want to show $V$ is isometry that is not surjective,
I get stuck when to prove $V$ is not surjective

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=1$ for $x<1$ and $0$ for $x>1$ defines a function in $L^{2}$ and this is not in the range of $V$.

Comment: @Dear Kabo Murphy, this is great! thanks